# open inactive comport, insert username and password

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, serial-port

I am a little rusty with my VB. I am attempting to read a comport from PC that is inactive, open it, and then knowing what device is connected enter the username and password into the device. I feel like I perhaps improperly assigned a variable but, I cannot produce the output of the serial port recognizing the text "write" for the username or password. Here is what I have:

```
   Public Class Form1

   Dim myPort As New IO.Ports.SerialPort  'COM Ports detected on the system will be stored here
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Get the selected COM port’s name from the combo box.
    If Not myPort.IsOpen Then
        myPort.PortName = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
    End If
    ' Open the port.
    'Enable 
    myPort.DtrEnable = True
    myPort.Open()

    myPort.ReadLine()
    myPort.Write("User1" & 13 & 10)

    myPort.ReadLine()

    myPort.Write("PassWord" & 13 & 10)


End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be well received.

Comment: `Dim myPort As New IO.Ports.SerialPort` isn't VBScript syntax. I guess you use VB.Net. Change tags and edit question if so.

Comment: This line:  `myPort.Write("User1" & 13 & 10)` is not doing what you think it is.  Go into your project's properties and turn `Option Strict` on.

Comment: As Chris pointed out, the &13 &10 aren't working the way you think.  You should do something like `char LF = (char)10;` and `char CR = (char)13;`  Then you can do `myPort.Write("User1" + CR + LF);`

Comment: I didn't see a build or warning error for doing this, but doing the carriage return and Line feed in that manner is sufficient for making the next prompt occur. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Does the program throw any exceptions or errors?
You can try `try` `catch` to test it.

```
Public Sub SendData(ByVal sendData As String)
    Try
        sp.Encoding = EncodingType
        sp.Write(sendData)
    Catch e As Exception
        Throw e
    End Try
End Sub
```